# Calculate mean in each element in a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of elements (each of them with different dimensions). The first two elements look like this:

```
> str(ldf[[1]]) 
'data.frame':   23 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ V1 : Factor w/ 23 levels "RS_number","rs11489820",..: 1 4 13 16 3 5 6 20 17 19 ...
 $ V2 : Factor w/ 10 levels "0.344","0.494",..: 10 9 8 1 4 7 4 7 7 6 ...
 $ V3 : Factor w/ 10 levels "0.235","0.357",..: 10 8 9 1 7 6 7 6 6 5 ...
 $ V4 : Factor w/ 11 levels "0.235","0.318",..: 11 4 1 10 5 8 5 2 2 3 ...
 $ V5 : Factor w/ 12 levels "0.35","0.502",..: 12 3 2 1 11 10 11 9 9 8 ...
 $ V6 : Factor w/ 12 levels "0.376","0.446",..: 12 3 2 1 10 11 10 9 9 8 ...
 $ V7 : Factor w/ 12 levels "0.35","0.502",..: 12 3 2 1 11 10 11 9 9 8 ...

> str(ldf[[2]]) 
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 2 levels "RS_number","rs34687326": 1 2
 $ V2: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","rs34687326": 2 1
```

I am trying to calculate the mean of all values within element 1. I have used the following command.

```
sapply(ldf, mean)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
I am getting an error: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: The column called `V1` is non-numeric, so exclude this in your `sapply`. Moreover, the first row is not numeric, so exclude it too: ``sapply(ldf[-1,-1], mean)``

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have modified my question mentioning that not all elements in my list have the same dimensions. So your command give this error: Error in ldf[-1, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions.

Comment: Problems pointed out by @Jonas could be solved with properly importing the data (`header = TRUE`).

Comment: The factors has to be converted to numeric  and this might work, apply(df, 2, function(x){ mean(as.integer(x))})

Comment: None of the above suggestions work. > sapply(ldf[-1,-1], mean)
Error in ldf[-1, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions. I get the same error when I add header=TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

You have to efficiently sort out *all* columns of *all* `data.frame`s in your list that are not numeric. Then, you can calculate the mean successfully. Try the following code.

---

**Code**

```
lapply(ldf, function(x) { y <- x[, sapply(x, is.numeric)]; mean(y)})
```

---

Testing this with the following example data works for me,

```
df3 = data.frame(V1 = c("Hello", "World", "first"), V2 = c(1, 2, 3),    
                 V3 = c("Hello", "World", "Again"))
A = list(df3, df3, df3)
lapply(ldf, function(x) { y <- x[, sapply(x, is.numeric)]; mean(y)})
```

gives the output

```
> lapply(A, function(x) { y <- x[, sapply(x, is.numeric)]; mean(y)})
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(A, ~ .x %>% 
       summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

#### data

```
df3 <- data.frame(V1 = c("Hello", "World", "first"), V2 = c(1, 2, 3),    
                 V3 = c("Hello", "World", "Again"))
A <- list(df3, df3, df3)
```